# Javascript bitshift alternative to math.round

Tags: javascript

```
var1=anyInteger
var2=anyInteger

(Math.round(var1/var2)*var2)
```

What would be the syntax for JavaScripts bitshift alternative for the above?

Using integer not floating

Thank you

Comment: The pn and sn are simply variables for integers. Could just as well be (Math.round(2/4)*4).
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you mean bit shifting?  Bit shifting would double or half the value for each shift you do.  If var2 were always a power of 2 then it would work, but if var2 was ever an odd number the logic to handle it would be more overhead than just dividing it.

Comment: read this several times and still don't understand your question .. please rephrase what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok, doesn't a bitwise shift of zero (>>0) always round down?
so just trying to find a bitwise shift formula that can round up or down depending on the values of the var's.

Comment: >>0 is a no-op .. what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Scott: Any bitwise operator in JS truncates the number to an integer, so it's not a no-op.
@cube: I don't think it's possible without an additional `if`.

Comment: Heres some alternative methods to rounding I just stumbled across

- Flooring and rounding
You may be used to the Math library but when going short, you need every byte you can get. Internally, most bit-wise operators actually do a 32bit cast first. This means that whenever you apply a float to a bit-wise operator, the result will be the operation of the floored argument instead. That's why these are the same for all numbers: Math.floor(x), ~~x, x|0. To round, simply add .5 to the argument first.

Full article found here http://qfox.nl/notes/111

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[UPDATED]
The quick answer:

`var intResult = ((((var1 / var2) + 0.5) << 1) >> 1) * var2;`

It's faster than the `Math.round()` method provided in the question and provides the exact same values.

Bit-shifting is between 10 and 20% faster from my tests. Below is some updated code that compares the two methods.

The code below has four parts: first, it creates 10,000 sets of two random integers; second, it does the round in the OP's question, stores the value for later comparison and logs the total time of execution; third, it does an equivalent bit-shift, stored the value for later comparison, and logs the execution time; fourth, it compares the Round and Bit-shift values to find any differences. It should report no anomalies.

Note that this should work for all positive, non-zero values. If the code encounters a zero for the denominator, it will raise and error, and I'm pretty sure that negative values will not bit-shift correctly, though I've not tested.

```
var arr1 = [],
    arr2 = [],
    arrFloorValues = [],
    arrShiftValues = [],
    intFloorTime = 0,
    intShiftTime = 0,
    mathround = Math.round, // @trinithis's excellent suggestion
    i;

// Step one: create random values to compare
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    arr1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    arr2.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
}

// Step two: test speed of Math.round()
var intStartTime = new Date().getTime();
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arrFloorValues.push(mathround(arr1[i] / arr2[i]) * arr2[i]);
}
console.log("Math.floor(): " + (new Date().getTime() - intStartTime));

// Step three: test speed of bit shift
var intStartTime = new Date().getTime();
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arrShiftValues.push( ( ( ( (arr1[i] / arr2[i]) + 0.5) << 1 ) >> 1 ) * arr2[i]);

}
console.log("Shifting: " + (new Date().getTime() - intStartTime));

// Step four: confirm that Math.round() and bit-shift produce same values
intMaxAsserts = 100;
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arrShiftValues[i] !== arrFloorValues[i]) {
        console.log("failed on",arr1[i],arr2[i],arrFloorValues[i],arrShiftValues[i])
        if (intMaxAsserts-- < 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check, but perhaps keeping a direct reference to `Math.round`, say `var round = Math.round;` would give a more accurate result.

Comment: True. It does shave about 2% off the execution time on Firefox and Chrome. In the latest Safari (which is abou 5x faster), the difference is negligible. I do think that there is a problem with my bit-shifting math though. I'm working to correct that.

Comment: Adding 0.5 does apparently leave the same value as Math.round(). Updating answer. I've tested for only positive integers and I think this will not work with any integer less than 1.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, and  trinithis as well. Andrew, I have Google'd for days trying to find any kind of write up, blog, or anything, on making a more efficient rounding method. I could find not one single note on the subject. You are brilliant! Thanks again!

Comment: Very happy to help. It was an interesting problem! I also learned something from this. Back in primary school, I learned that decimal numbers that lay exactly between two whole numbers are supposed to round to the nearest even number (i.e. 1.5 -> 2, 2.5 -> 2,3.5 -> 4,etc.). In JS, these numbers always round up (towards positive infinity). That tidbit simplified the logic a lot!

Comment: @Andrew - Wow, you learned "banker's rounding" in primary school. I learned the simple round-up method and had never even heard of banker's rounding until after college.

Answer (score 6):

you should be able to round any number by adding 0.5 then shifting off the decimals...

```
var anyNum = 3.14;
var rounded = (anyNum + 0.5) | 0;
```

so the original expression could be solved using this (instead of the slower Math.round)

`((var1/var2 + 0.5)|0) * var2`

Run the code snippet below to test different values...

```js
function updateAnswer() {
  var A = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var B = document.getElementById('b').value;

  var h = "Math.round(A/B) * B = <b>" + (Math.round(A/B) * B) + "</b>";
  h += "<br/>";
  h += "((A/B + 0.5)|0) * B = <b>" + ((A/B + 0.5) | 0) * B +"</b>";
  
  document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = h;
}
```

```css
*{font-family:courier}
```

```html
  A: <input id="a" value="42" />
  <br/>
  B: <input id="b" value="7" />
  <br/><br/>
  <button onclick="updateAnswer()">go</button>
  <hr/>
  <span id="ans"></span>
```

Comment: Not good if you are targetting numbers up to 32 bits: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7487977/1525495

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález greater than*

Comment: @GustvandeWal Yep, you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

If var2 is a power of two (2^k) you may
 write

```
(var1>>k)<<k
```

but in the general case
 there is no straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `(var | 0)` - that would truncate the number to an integer, but you'll always get the floor value. If you want to round it, you'll need an additional `if` statement, but in this case `Math.round` would be faster anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, bit shifting operations usually only work with integers. Are your variables integers or floats?

Comment: The pn and sn are simply variables for integers. Could just as well be (Math.round(2/4)*4). Thank you