# Javascript math efficiency rounding

Tags: javascript, performance, math, rounding

Will this script

```
var a = 1/3;
var b = 2/5;
var c = a+b;
```

run faster or slower than this script

```
var a = Math.round(100*(1/3))/100;
var b = Math.round(100*(2/5))/100;
var c = a+b;
```

Or rather, is there a way to get javascript to evaluate an equation to only a certain level of accuracy.

```
var a = Math.onlySolveThisUpTo2DecimalPlaces(1/3); //0.33
```

Is the speed difference even large enough to care about?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil...

Comment: I've had a question about `Math.round()` effeciency also. Consider bitshifting if speed is of upmost importance. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233731/javascript-bitshift-alternative-to-math-round

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this script […] run faster or slower than this script

Faster. There’s much more to do in the second.

> Or rather, is there a way to get javascript to evaluate an equation to only a certain level of accuracy.

No.

> Is the speed difference even large enough to care about?

No.

If you want to *display* the result with a certain precision, you can use `a.toFixed(2)` (two decimal places) or `a.toPrecision(2)` (two significant digits). But rounding (and not even to integers) isn’t going to positively affect performance.